# Mongo Collection (using Meteor) to compare string value of key inside document

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to have the find return all matching documents where the orderStatus is either 'Pending' or 'In Progress' , what is the easiest way to perform this query? Much thanks!

```
MyCollection.find({ user: currentUserId,
    { $or:
      [{orderStatus : "Pending"},
       {orderStatus : "In Progress"}] }});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **[`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)** operator as follows:

```
MyCollection.find({ 
    "user": currentUserId,
    "orderStatus": { "$in": ["Pending", "In Progress"] }
});
```

The above query is a much simpler version of the following query with the **`$or`** operator:

```
MyCollection.find({ 
    "user": currentUserId,
    "$or": [
        { "orderStatus": "Pending" },
        { "orderStatus": "In Progress" }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks . Just what I needed "$in"  !